# FreeTextBox : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, google-chrome, freetextbox

I am using FreeTextBox and having Error when i am pressing Enter

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null`

**This issue is coming only on production server but not able to reproduce on my local machine.**

Google Chrome
Version 53.0.2785.143 m

Please help me to how should i fix this issue.
Any suggestion will be appreciated

Comment: Will this error appear on a other browser too?

Comment: Yes it is appearing on browser.